# proving tautology for $¬((∀x.(Q(x)∧P(x)))∧∃y.¬P(y))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that the following is a tautology. Not sure even where to start. Can I prove it by deduction?

$$¬\Big(\big(∀x.Q(x)∧P(x)\big)∧∃y.¬P(y)\Big)$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- You can prove it by deduction, but it's easier to do via sets operations.
- There is a 1-1 correspondence between unary predicates and sets (here $\Omega$ denotes the universe):
  \begin{align}
  A_\text{predicate}(x) & \text{ is } x \in A_\text{set}, \\
  A_\text{set} &\text{ is } \big\{x \in \Omega \mid A_\text{predicate}(x)\big\}.
  \end{align}
- Using sets your formula translates to
  $$\neg\Big((\forall x.\ x \in Q_\text{set} \land x \in P_\text{set})\land (\exists y.\ y \notin P_\text{set})\Big),$$
  that is,
  $$\neg\Big((Q_\text{set} \cap P_\text{set} = \Omega)\land (P_\text{set} \neq \Omega)\Big).$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$